# Hide Second Table Header in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have two tables in the Power BI having same columns header. I want to hide the columns header of the second table (bottom one). How can we do that please?

FYI, Please check the below table

[image]

Comment: What about appending the rows and show them in a single table? What will you do when the user resizes some column in the top table?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Actually i'm replicating my PPT template into Power BI. There are multiple tables from different data source but header will be same for each table. How can we combine these multiple tables?

Comment: With [Append queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries) command.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Thanks for sharing the link! The name "Actual" is already used for a measure in the second table (bottom one). There is also a cell format issue.
In the first table, Actual column is in my raw data i.e. in number format. While the 'Actual' column in the second below table (value in %) is a measure which was calculated by DAX formula i.e. .  not available in my raw data. I'm not able to combine it